# Boostrap 4 dropdown menu is exceeding the page on the right

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I added a dropdown menu to my bootstrap4 navbar, but the dropdown menu exceeds the page by quite a bit (on the right side).

I tried applying a few things I saw on google like adding `dropdown-menu-left` or `drop-left` but both haven't worked for me. The only thing that works at the moment is applying margin-right to the element but that's not what I want since it ruins the format of my navbar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhcOW.jpg

My html

```
        <!-- right side -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          @if (isset($_SESSION['user_data']))
          <!-- Dropdown -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="right: 0;">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{$_SESSION['user_data']->username}}
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropleft">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/servers') }}">Manage servers</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          @else 

          @endif

       </ul>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to https://imgur.com/ and link it to your post please?
I think with the code you're giving it will be difficult to see the problem, can you post at least all your header code please?

Comment: I keep getting errors posting a picture, so I added the imgur link to the post. Sorry about that!

Comment: have you tried dropdown-menu-right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `dropdown-menu-right` on your `dropdown-menu` ?

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/servers') }}">Manage servers</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Logout</a>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/aev4dz9L/) for that (try to enlarge the preview window if you see the mobile layout).

Is it what you're looking for?

See bootstrap4 documentation for more details on [menu alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment)

Comment: Apparently I did something wrong when trying this, it seems to work fine now. Thank you for the help.